# How to evaluate the integral $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(a^2+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

My question is that I want to evaluate step-by-step the integral

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(a^2+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

where $a$ is some constante in the real numbers and $x$ is also a real number.

**My attempt:** If $x = \sin(u)$ then the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^{\arcsin(1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+(\sin(u)/a)^2}$$

Then I can get to other places but this isn't quite good. Like using another change of the variables. From wolfram this integral get's in to a $\tan^{-1}$ function.

Comment: upper limit is $\arcsin(1)=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $x=\sin u$ we have,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sin^2(u)+a^2} du$$

Dividing top and bottom by $\cos^2 u$ gives,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^2 u}{\tan^2 u+a^2 \sec^2 u} du$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^2 u}{\tan^2 u+a^2(\tan^2 u+1)} du$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(a^2+1)\tan^2 u+a^2} du$$

Now with $\tan u=v$ we have,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a^2+1)v^2+a^2} dv$$

I think you can handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Hint...when you do the substitution $x=\sin u$ you get $$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a^2+\sin^2u}du$$

Now do the substitution $t=\tan u$ and the integral becomes$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2+(a^2+1)t^2}dt$$

Can you finish this?